# Turning JSON file content into Javascript object

Tags: javascript, json

What I want to do is read the JSON from a file and turn it into an array in Javascript.

My JSON looks like this

```
{
  "3-2": "10",
  "3-3": "20",
  "3-4": "30",
  "5-1": "4",
  "5-3": "8"
}
```

I know I should include the code I'm working with, but I've tried so many different ways and I cannot get anything to even remotely work, so I'm just looking for a simple solution (I'm using jQuery).

I just want to fetch the content of my JSON file, turn it into an array, and then be able to run a `for` loop to alert each item in the array.

Comment: Well, this is no array, so do you want to alert the keys or the values, or both? A simple solution would be `let o = JSON.parse(fileContent); for (let p in o) alert(\`${p} = ${o[p]}\`)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const json = '{"3-2":"10","3-3":"20","3-4":"30","5-1":"4","5-3":"8"}'
const obj = JSON.parse(json)
const arr = Object.entries(obj)

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  const [key, val] = arr[i]
  console.log(`key: ${key}`)
  console.log(`val: ${val}`)
}
```

Comment: This works, but the result for each item in array reads like `3-2,10`. How would I get the `key` and `value` separately?

Comment: There are a few ways to do that. My preferred would be array destructuring. See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks! If you can wrap your answer inside this (and remove the `const json` line, then I can mark it as the solution `fetch('file.json') .then(response => response.text()) .then(json => { YOUR SOLUTION });`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```js
const yourJSON = {
  "3-2": "10",
  "3-3": "20",
  "3-4": "30",
  "5-1": "4",
  "5-3": "8"
}

for (key in yourJSON)
  console.log(key,":",yourJSON[key]) // here's your loop without converting into array
```